# How to get a DMChannel object? - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to check what is the channel with the new emoji and then do different things, depends on what the new emoji is. It works properly until the emoji is on a private channel, which makes the `bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)` return None.

I had the same problem with a user or member id. The `payload.member` returns None, but `bot.get_user(payload.user_id)` returns the member object. So, is there something like this but with channels? What is used to get the DMChannel object?

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
print(bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id), payload.channel_id) # This line will be deleted, it is used for showing the problem.
if payload.user_id != None:
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji
    author = payload.member
    if emoji.is_custom_emoji():
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji=emoji).count
    else:
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji = emoji.name).count
    if payload.channel_id == channel_i:
        if emoji_count > 1:
           ...
```

The output if the reaction is in a DM channel, the error occurs because the channel is NoneType, which is caused by the previous line.

```
None 782664385889959976
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\plays\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\bot2.py", line 122, in on_raw_reaction_add
msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you need to use `on_raw_reaction_add` rather than `on_reaction_add`? In 99% of cases the latter does the same as the former. That being said its parameters are `reaction, user` [[documentation]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) which are much more easily parseable, because they are discord.py objects.

Rather than retrieving the channel by `bot.get_channel` you can then just can just call

```py
channel = reaction.channel.message
```

Full example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = reaction.message.channel
```

Comment: on_raw_reaction_add works for messages not in cache, and works for messages older than 14 days. So yes that seems like a thing he would want

Comment: Alright, seems that I'll not find an answer, so I will try to divide `on_raw_reaction_add` and add a `on_reaction_add`. In that case, I need to check if the channel is a dm channel. There is a `isinstance()` for that, but how to use it if the `channel` is always `None` if it is a DMChannel?

Answer (score 2):

If you require to use `on_raw_reaction_add`, you can use `bot.private_channels` [(Documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.private_channels) combined with `discord.utils.get`[(Documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) (remember to check your imports for that one) to fetch the DM channel.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
if payload.user_id != None:
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if channel is None: # checking if we are in a DM channel
        channel = discord.utils.get(bot.private_channels, id=payload.channel_id)
```

Comment: `channel` is None anyway. It is probably because `...get(bot.private_channels...` is searching is a list of `discord.abc.PrivateChannel` objects, and the only attribute of them is `me`, so there is no attribute `id` (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.PrivateChannel)

Comment: @Tony_I that is wrong, the private channels returned are either ```DMChannel``` (docs)[https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.DMChannel.id] or ```GroupChannel``` (docs)[https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.GroupChannel.id] which both have id attributes.

Comment: Whatever the reason is, the problem is still there, `discord.utils.get(...) ` and `bot.get_channel(...)` both return None

Answer (score 1):

I added a new function `on_reaction_add`. It will respond and do different things in private channels, while `on_raw_reaction_add` will raise if reactions are in Guild.
The problem that `on_reaction_add` works only with messages in the cache is solvable in my case. The server with the bot has channels with exact messages which are not editable at all, so no one can add NEW reactions, only increase the amount of already existing ones. When someone clicks the reaction, he will get different reactions depends on what is the emoji he clicked. One of the reactions is sending a private message (in DMChannel) and adding reactions to it, and since the bot is not turning off, he has this message in the cache (because he sent it). Now, if the user increases the amount of emojis that the bot added, the bot will react in some way. To check if the channel is a DMChannel, I have written `if "None" in str(type(channel))` in the first function and `if isinstance((reaction.message.channel), discord.channel.DMChannel):` in other.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
if payload.user_id != 773501851396079618 and not "None" in str(type(channel)):
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji
    author = payload.member
    if emoji.is_custom_emoji():
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji=emoji).count
    else:
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji = emoji.name).count
    ...
    ...

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if isinstance((reaction.message.channel), discord.channel.DMChannel):
        ...
```